# How to flush routing cache in Linux?

Tags: ip, routing, cache, oracle-linux

There is an Oracle Linux 7 system with Unbreakable kernel `5.4.17-2136.304.4.1.el7uek.x86_64` (which is very recent for the RHEL7-like system, which usually uses 3.10-based kernel).

Network interfaces have several addresses configured as aliases (I know the aliases only needed for ancient `ifconfig`, but nonetheless); some of IPs are historic, but not all and the system is still required to have several addresses:

```
root@bccdb:network-scripts# ip addr show dev bond0.610
15: bond0.610@bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.221.195/24 brd 192.168.221.255 scope global bond0.610
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.221.2/24 brd 192.168.221.255 scope global secondary bond0.610:1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.221.134/24 brd 192.168.221.255 scope global secondary bond0.610:2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

There is a problem with routing cache and hints (the address that system uses when makes outgoing connections).

The `.195` address was up first, so it was made into the local-network route (`192.168.221.0/24 dev bond0.610 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.221.195`). But the system should use the `.134` by default.

We updated this route with `ip route change 192.168.221.0/24 dev bond0.610 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.221.134`), and `ip route` now shows correct route. But when I ask for concrete IPs, it still uses the old src hint:

```
root@bccdb:network-scripts# ip route get 8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8 via 192.168.221.1 dev bond0.610 src 192.168.221.195 uid 0 
    cache
```

And it actually uses this source address for any destination addresses *except* the routes which we install by hand with `ip route add <target-host> dev bond0.610 src 192.168.221.134` (and, if the address is in another network, with added `via 192.167.221.1`), where `<target-host>` is target host's address (/32).

`ip route show cache` displays nothing.

The general cache was [removed in Linux 3.6](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/netdev/net-next.git/commit/?id=89aef8921bfbac22f00e04f8450f6e447db13e42) and we are running much newer version of it. There are some explanations in [routing cache in latest Linux kernels](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207535/routing-cache-in-latest-linux-kernels) , but there are no suggestions about managing of this cache.

I found [this suggestion](http://pandaeatsbamboo.blogspot.com/2009/07/clear-route-cache-on-your-linux-box.html), but `ip route flush cache` did not help.

How to clear this cache?

Comment: While the system in question is free from the problem now, I am still able to repeat this problem in test system, so I'll wait to see if somebody comes with the zero downtime solution, which I'll accept.

Answer (score 0):

This was an important system, and because the solution did not come before the management time frame, we simply restarted the interface with `ifdown bond0.610` followed by `ifup bond0.610`, which also resulted in the routing table flush (for this interface). This resulted in around 5 second downtime, which is barely acceptable for this server.